# increasing a number & duplicating a div is not working together at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

So it possible that, increase the number & duplicate the div down by one click on a button? I want to click on "*Add another shirt"* then The number will increase & duplicate the div at the same time. I don't know how to do that. I am working on this file for some hours but It did not worked. I need a solution

**html**

```
<div id="filter" class="measurements-content">
  <div class="table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Shirt No.</th>
        <th colspan="2">Logo/Brand Location</th>
        <th colspan="6">Measurements (Inch)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2"><input type="text" id="number" value="1" /></th>
        <td>Logo</td>
        <td>Brand Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="check-content">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <p>Front</p>
          </div>
          <div class="check-content">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <p>Back</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="check-content-arm">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <p>Left Arm</p>
          </div>
          <div class="check-content-arm">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <p>Right Arm</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The button I will click**

```
<div id="filter-nav" class="continue-button">
  <a
    class="btn and-button"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    id="and-button"
    onclick="incrementValue()"
    >Add another shirt</a
  >
</div>
```

**Scripts**

```
//add another shirt
document.getElementById("and-button").onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById("filter");
var beforeElem = document.getElementById("filter-nav");
function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "filter" + ++i;
  original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, beforeElem);
}

//increasing value 1++
function incrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById("number").value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two functions cannot be executed simultaneously with one html element.

You can execute function in one another function.

```js
let i = 0;
let number = 1;
const original = document.getElementById("filter");
const beforeElem = document.getElementById("filter-nav");
function duplicate() {
  const clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "filter" + ++i;
  incrementValue(clone); // You can execute function in one another function.
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}

function incrementValue(cloneNode) {
  cloneNode.querySelector("#number").value = ++number;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="filter" class="measurements-content">
    <div class="table">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="1">Shirt No.</th>
          <th colspan="2">Logo/Brand Location</th>
          <th colspan="6">Measurements (Inch)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">
            <input type="text" id="number" value="1" />
          </th>
          <td>Logo</td>
          <td>Brand Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="check-content">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <p>Front</p>
            </div>
            <div class="check-content">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <p>Back</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="check-content-arm">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <p>Left Arm</p>
            </div>
            <div class="check-content-arm">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <p>Right Arm</p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="filter-nav" class="continue-button">
  <a
    class="btn and-button"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    id="and-button"
    onclick="duplicate();"
    >Add another shirt</a
  >
</div>
```